# K&R qsort understanding

Tags: c, sorting

I have a question about this part of code(in bold):

```
/* swap: interchange v[i] and v[j] */
void swap(int v[], int i, int j)
{
  int temp;
  temp = v[i];
  v[i] = v[j];
  v[j] = temp;
}

/* qsort: sort v[left]...v[right] into increasing order */
void qsort(int v[], int left, int right)
{
  int i, last;
  if (left >= right) /* do nothing if array contains */
      return; /* fewer than two elements */
  swap(v, left, (left + right)/2); /* move partition elem */
  last = left; /* to v[0] */
  for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
      if (v[i] < v[left])
          swap(v, ++last, i);
  swap(v, left, last); /* restore partition elem */
  qsort(v, left, last-1);
  qsort(v, last+1, right);
}
```

The part I do not understand is:

```
last = left; /* to v[0] */
for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
    if (v[i] < v[left])
        swap(v, ++last, i);
```

So if `left` initialized to `0`. So `last` will be equal zero.
Then in the for loop we have `i` equal to `1` and if:

```
if (v[i] < v[left])
```

Then

```
swap(v, ++last, i);
```

But where is the point of this swap? Doesn't `last` became `1` when passed to function with pre-incrementation? So `++last`  == `i` == `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it clearer when you indent it properly?

```
last = left; /* to v[0] */
for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
  if (v[i] < v[left])
    swap(v, ++last, i);
```

That line of code does not run only once, and `i` is not always equal to `last` + 1.  On the first iteration, it might end up swapping `v[i]` with itself.

Comment: And that's why not using braces is often a bad idea

Comment: I just copy this code from book. So, ok we have: {3, 2, 1}. So if i read this code it means 2 < 3. I will exchange 2 vs itself. Second iteration in loop for: i == 2 and we have 1 < 2 and we make swap, so last == 2 also, i will exchange 1 vs itself? It is correct?

Comment: You’re right.  And that’s how quickSort becomes veryVerySlowSort when the data is in exactly the wrong order.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I was a little bit confused. Why they add such useless code. But how they describe in book it is for education purpose only and not very efficient.

Comment: @Simon: You are confusing bracing everything with proper formatting. A common enough failing.

Comment: The code’s not useless.  The comparison controls whether `left` increments or not.  There are, possibly, unnecessary swaps—but swaps are a single machine-language instruction on many architectures, and if you spent too much time avoiding those, all sorts would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
    last = left; /* to v[0] */
for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++) /* partition */
    if (v[i] < v[left])
        swap(v, ++last, i);
```

Because `i` is not always equals to `++last` and `i` increases more quickly than `last` variable in the loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).